# Query from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile is very slow

Tags: c#

I'm using C# to querying Name,LastLogon,PasswordExpires,UserType from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile, but it's very slow, it takes about 150 seconds to return result. Is there a way to optimize the query? Or there's a better way to get the information I need?

Here is my code:

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Name,LastLogon,PasswordExpires,UserType FROM WIN32_NETWORKLOGINPROFILE WHERE Name LIKE '%" + System.Environment.UserName + "%'");
 searcher.Options.ReturnImmediately = true;
 var result = searcher.Get();
```

Comment: Why do you do a `LIKE` search?

Comment: Forget the LIKE, I found it takes almost same time between using LIKE or = in WHERE clause, or even no condition at all.